# How did Log Horizon members find out Tetra's real gender?

Tags: log-horizon

Before the raid on Depths of Palm (Gold of the Kunie) in Susukino where Shiroe looks for full party members, Naotsugu and Regan find Tetra. Later on in the raid of Depths of Palm, Tetra joins (or is permitted to join) Log Horizon.

It seems that all members of Log Horizon, except Naotsugu, know that Tetra is actually male. How is that?

Comment: By skinship, perhaps. Touching female feels different than touching male.

Comment: @AyaseEri Since Tetra spends 90% of time hugging Naotsugu, I wouldn't say, that this is the case.

Comment: Most of the times when Tetra hugs Naotsugu, the latter is wearing his armor.

Comment: @AyaseEri [Log Horizon wiki](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Tetora) claims, that Kazukiho disclosed true gender of Tetra during conversation with Shiroe in Depths of Palm raid. So Shiroe maybe revealed that fact to other members of Log Horizon, with exception to Naotsugu.

Comment: @AyaseEri Also note Tetra might be a Female Avatar. Just like Akatsuki who had a Male avatar initially until she consumed the cosmetic Potion.

Comment: @Ryan [It usually is](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48693/tetras-avatars-gender-which-one-is-it). She's only a feminine man in the mobile game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shiroe learned Tetra's secret by intuition, but he left it up to Tetra to tell Naotsugu that he's a dude. I doubt Shiroe kept it a secret from anyone else but Naotsugu since Tetra only said that he wants to tell Naotsugu himself.