# Tetra's avatar's gender: which one is it?

Tags: log-horizon

In the anime, Tetra appears feminine at first, but it's later reveled that he is a boy. However, in the anime, it's not clear if they refer to the avatar or just the player.

Is Tetra's avatar's gender female?  [The wikia](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Tetora) is unclear, making statements that his avatar is female, androgynous, and is defined as a "he" in his "New Adventure Land profile" (no idea what that is).

The wiki makes it obvious that the player is male; I'm asking about the avatar.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* intentionally ambiguous, which has caused it to be handled differently across the franchise.

### What's your avatar's gender?

- Official database: "Off-limits"
- Light novel: "Tetra-chan", looks female
- Anime: "Tetra-chan", looks female
- NAL mobile game: "Male", looks female

Why's it important to put baby in a corner?

Answer (score 0):

His wikia is quite clear about his avatar, **female Human-Cleric**:

> Tetra used a female Human Cleric-Idol character at the time of the Catastrophe and was thus stuck in it

Comment: Rando editing of the Wiki's infobox doesn't make it canon. Read the rest of the article.